# quickblox try to add new emai id and user name but sometime this error come in ios

Tags: ios, quickblox

errors =     {
        email =         (
            "has already been taken"
        );
        "external_user_id" =         (
            "has already been taken"
        );
        login =         (
            "has already been taken"
        );
    };

Answer (score 2):

email or external_user_id or login already taken by other registered user? Please ensure its unique data.